# How to install my app to client's iPhone without iTunes Connect

Tags: ios

Recently i got an order to create a iOS app. The problem is that the man made the order is really far from me and he want to test the app before i publish it to iTunes. He is not a developer himself. How that could be done?

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple.

In one word: [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link. The only thing you need to do is to make zip of your build and drag it to the area provided in site. It will provide a link which you can open on test device on browser and all the things would be done!!

[link](http://www.diawi.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [This for wireless installation](http://www.diawi.com/)

Thanks.